# JSTL Items not getting displayed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

have a very simple question on JSTL tags.
I am using spring to fetch data from back-end and display in the JSP.

Have the following code. I am getting the items of the for each tag printed in the console. But the same items are not getting printed/displayed inside the table rows.

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>Movie Name</th>
        <th>Movie Rating</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${model.movieslist}" var="movie">
    <tr>
        <td>${movie.name}</td>
        <td>${movie.rating}</td>
    </tr>

    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

My spring controller class

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logger.info("returning hello view");
    List<Movie> moviesList = DbManager.getInstance().getMovies();
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    modelMap.addAttribute("movieslist", moviesList);
    return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp",modelMap);
}
```

Movie domain class

```
 package springapp.domain;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
@Document(collection = "movie")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    public String _id;

    public String name;
    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public float rating;
    public String date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you adding objects to the model attribute .if added try to debug if the value is getting passed .check if the names are similar .that is the name used in model attribute and the name in the jsp

Comment: @ManojRamanan thanks for the reply...added the code for my spring controller and domain object

Comment: can you try using movielist alone not with model.movielist try movielist alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your jsp should contain the following taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Second, you don't need to get it using ${model.moviesList}, modify it as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${movieslist}" var="movie">
```

Comment: thanks a lot ...both were the reasons for my issue...its resolved now